# Apache Ignite crash on startup

Tags: entity-framework, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite entity framework Nuget as a second level cache in an ApsNetCore 2.0 web application under IIS(as reverse proxy).
On my development machine (VS2017 Windows 8.1) everything works well. Wen i deploy to WindowsServer 2012 the Ignite crash at startup with :

An error occurred while starting the application.
IgniteException: Failed to load jvm.dll (Please specify IgniteConfiguration.JvmDllPath or JAVA_HOME.)
Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.Load(string configJvmDllPath, ILogger log)

TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, bool publicOnly, bool noCheck, ref bool canBeCached, ref RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor, ref bool bNeedSecurityCheck)

IgniteException: Failed to load jvm.dll (Please specify IgniteConfiguration.JvmDllPath or JAVA_HOME.)
Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.Load(string configJvmDllPath, ILogger log)
Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
Apache.Ignite.EntityFramework.IgniteDbConfiguration.GetOrStartIgnite(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
Apache.Ignite.EntityFramework.IgniteDbConfiguration..ctor()

I checked and re-chewed, installed the JDK , correct system variables....everything. The error don't goes away. What is interesting is the application run ok as console. When it runs under IIS(reverse proxy) it crashes at startup with the above error.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you have multiple JAVA runtimes? Also what version do you use? If it's not the latest one, then you might have faced a known bug, will post it here later

Comment: Another guess - check that you don't have x64-x86 mismatch and both the JRE and Ignite targets the same, most likely x64, platform.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to start the website. How ? Only with JDK 11 and explicit path to jvm.dll on app.config file:

If is not explicit in config then crashes.
The JAVA_HOME from system variable is correct set. Also the Path variable is

%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\server;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Memurai;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\

Maybe is a conflict with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\ ? It carsh with jvm 15. But it works with jvm 11

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the IIS worker process is running in 32-bit mode, so Ignite looks for a 32-bit JDK, which is not present.

And the console app runs in 64-bit mode, using 64-bit JDK, so it works.

Please check the app pool settings in `IIS Manager -> Application Pools -> select the app pool you want and -> Advanced Settings`.

Additionally, you can enable detailed logging to a file (since you can't see console logs in IIS) - Ignite logs all attempts to resolve the JDK path. For example, with `Apache.Ignite.NLog` package:

```
var nlogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
var fileTarget = new FileTarget
{
    FileName = "/home/pavel/w/ignite_nlog.log"
};
nlogConfig.AddTarget("logfile", fileTarget);
nlogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget));
LogManager.Configuration = nlogConfig;

var igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration
{
    Logger = new IgniteNLogLogger()
};

Ignition.Start(igniteConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I really appreciate it ! I've checked the app pool; Enable 32bits=false. This is the only one option regarding 32/64 bits. I'll try to install the ignite log package and i'll be back with the result

Comment: Also i've tried to to specified JvmDllPath="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-15.0.1\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll" . Now it crash with : IgniteException: Failed to load jvm.dll ([option=IgniteConfiguration.JvmDllPath, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ])

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the suggested points by Pavel Tupitsyn:

1. App pool aplication is 64bits  (emable 32bits=false)
2. I've installed apache.Ignite.NLog
   I'tested it on my machine and it logs well all java resolves.
   I've deployed to windows server 2012 and under IIS i'm getting 'Process Failure'.
   The log file looks like:

2020-12-07 19:39:38.3304|DEBUG||Starting Ignite.NET 2.9.0.50002
2020-12-07 19:39:38.3834|WARN||GC server mode is not enabled, this could lead to less than optimal performance on multi-core machines (to enable see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx).
2020-12-07 19:39:46.2534|DEBUG||Starting Ignite.NET 2.9.0.50002

so...just a warning (present on my machine too).

Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info:

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.Load(System.String, Apache.Ignite.Core.Log.ILogger)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfiguration)
   at Nop.Web.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

well...adding apache.ingite.nlog throws PROCESS FAILURE
Hosting is virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 64bits

Any other ideas please....